# Using Address class for geocoding in bing maps ajax control

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I am using bing maps ajax control in a webapplication with a bing maps enterpise key.One of the modules include a functionality to geocode a list of addresses requested by the user.I am using the following code snippet to do the geocoding.

```
for (var i = 0, j = addresses.length; i < j; i++) {
     searchManager.geocode({
     where : addresses[i],/*<address>,<city>,<state>,<country>,<zip>*/
     count : 5,
     callback : success,
     errorCallback : failure
 });
 };
```

The success% is very less.Close to 10% even after multiple tries(about 150 addresses to geocode).
 So,I wanted to know if there is any way we can use the `Address` class(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868069.aspx) for geocoding instead of giving address as a string.The official documentation mentions only about giving address as a string(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868060.aspx). The reason I wanted to check with address class instead of string is because,with the bing maps SOAP api in a silverlight application,i had found the success% to be more while using Address class.

Thanks in advance for any help in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you have the address data somewhere you should geocode it ahead of time. Geocoding all your address in JavaScript with your map is slow and it also uses a lot of transactions thus making you run out of free usage fast. Is there a reason why you are geocoding addresses in a loop in a JavaScript app rather than geocoding a head of time?

It is often better to pass in the address as a single string and allow the geocoder to parse it. This is actually a tip the is used for the REST services as well when geocoding.

Comment: The addresses to geocode are uploaded by the end user. So geocoding it ahead of time wil not work.

Comment: The Address class can't be used in the search module for geocoding. You can however use the REST services directly to do this. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427601.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx